# PHP 7.2 Apache not executing all php code

Tags: php, html, apache

Really confusd here. PHP is working until it gets to an IF statement any suggestions / help greatly appreciated.

```
$sql2=("SELECT * FROM temporders WHERE cusid='$myid'");
$result2=mysqli_query($connP,$sql2);
$count2=mysqli_num_rows($result2);
$total=0;
$itemNum=0;
if ($count2>0) {
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, mysqli_ASSOC)) {
    $total=($total+($row2['price']*$row2['qty']));
    $itemNum=$itemNum+$row2['qty'];
    }
}
if ($total<1) {
$total=0;
} else {
$total=number_format($total, 2, '.', '');
}
?>
 <div class="basket">
```

All of the bove works perfect until it gets to here which is the next stage it produces this when i view the page source code. All php is showing from this stage onwards

```
<div class="basket">
<?
if ($total==0) {
?>
<form action="../customer-page.html" method="get" name="cart" id="cart">
<?
    } else {
?>
    <form>
<?
}
?>
      <input type="hidden" name="page" id="page" value="southern-spas-saunas.html" />
      <input type="hidden" name="delitem" value="0" />
      <input type="hidden" name="myid" value="202003220001" />
 <table width="250" border="0">
 <tr>
  <td width="45"><input name="image2" type="image" value="Process" src="../1basket.gif" /></td>
  <td width="120">Total &pound; 0</td>
  <td>Items 0</td>
</tr>
</table>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Looks like you don't have short tags enabled, and shouldn't. Use `<?php`.

Comment: Additionally, your mysqli usage is insecure. Parameterize the query.

Comment: You may have been using an older version, I think 5.3 came with that option enabled. That was the only version that had it defaulted to `on`.